# Partitioning Existing Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, partitioning

How do I partition existing table in SQL Server 2005/08? I couldn't find a better clue on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here is a full article](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3647561/Data-partitioning-in-SQL-Server-2005---Part-V.htm) on how to do this. (Create table, insert data, then partition)

Trick is to move the table to the new partition.

```
DROP INDEX MyTable_IXC ON MyTable WITH (Move To [Data Partition Scheme] (ID) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you give no errors I suppose you are looking for general information on how to do it? Partitioning is not something you can master in just a few seconds. Some information on the subject can be found in the following links.

SQL2005: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188706(SQL.90).aspx

SQL2008: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188706.aspx

sqlskills article http://www.sqlskills.com/resources/Whitepapers/Partitioning%20in%20SQL%20Server%202005%20Beta%20II.htm